# Why when I download the file, Chrome always says Faild - Network error

Tags: php, html, download, codeigniter-3

I use Codeignter and the address link was not problem and the upload method is places the file to the place i want. So Basically there was no problem with my href. Heres the code.

```
<?php 
 if($ticket_detail->attachment != null) 
 echo "<a href='".$ticket_detail->attachment."' download>Download</a>"; 
 else 
 echo '-';
?>
```

But when i always downloading it, the Chrome always says Failed - Network error